# Push doesn't act as expected?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

in the following function, `q` and `id` log 1 and 2 respectively but the order equals `1` instead of `{items: [{"product": 2, "quantity": 1}]}`.

```
function addToCart(id) {
        q = $('.shopify-buy__quantity').val();
        console.log("q: " + q)
        console.log("id: " + id)
        var order = {items: []}
        order = order.items.push({"product": id, "quantity": q})
        console.log('order: ' + order)
        order = JSON.stringify(order)
        storage.setItem('domehaOrder', order)
        updateCart()
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.push()` doesn't return the object that owns the array. It alters the array object itself by adding the new item to the end, and then it returns the new length of the array.

Just call it, don't assign the length of the array to `order`.

```
order.items.push({"product": id, "quantity": q})
```

`order.items` now has one item in it.

Answer (score 0):

remove the assignment `order = order.items.push({"product": id, "quantity": q})`

Just do `order.items.push({"product": id, "quantity": q})`